# Android backward compatibility

Tags: android, sdk, backwards-compatibility

Currently I am developing Android project for old sdk version.
However - new SDK versions have been released and thinking to use new features in the UI.

If I want the application to run also on the old SDK devices, how can I make a single APK for all devices (for new SDK devices will use new features)?
Is it possible?
Or should I create different releases?

Example - ActionBar is on SDK ver. 3.0 and latest, if I will include it - then will not be able to run on SDK ver. 2.1, but I still want to support the users who have the oldest SDK versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best approach is to use Android's compatibility library - http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Answer (score 2):

there are compatibility projects for Android.

for `ActionBar` try usin [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).

Comment: ActionBar was just an example. When I will look deeper into the new SDK I am sure will find out lots ot new stuff I might want to use. But still - there are lots of devices with older SDK version that I want to support. Currently the idea is to support old devices and according to statistics - see how many old sdk devices are and increment SDK version accordingly\

Comment: there is no way to use new objects in an old SDK. that is why there are compatibility libraries all you need to do is search for them, I posted `ActionBarSherlock` because it was an answer to your example. there are many more. all you need to do is search

Comment: forward them to http://www.cyanogenmod.com/ and use at least 2.3.x Lots of stuff went deprecated for a reason. Just an opinion.